# The definition of Compactness for "set" and "space"

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Compactness for "set" and "space"

I was wondering if there is any significance between the two settings. Do we treat them as two different things?

For example, let $(X,d)$ be a metric space with the topology induced by the metric $d$. From Heine-Borel theorem (for metric space), we know that the following are equivalent:

- Every sequence has a convergent subsequence;
- $X$ is a compact space.

And this is wrong about sets, take $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}_n$ in $[0,1]$, it has a convergent subsequence, but it is only pre-compact (its closure is compact).

**Edit:** I guess if you take $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}_n$ as a subspace, it does not have any convergent subsequence, therefore not a compact subspace (or set). So the two settings are actually the same?

Comment: "Set" is often used lazily (and I include myself amongst the lazy people) as a synonym for "Space".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term *space* is often used for the set with structure, so compact set/space is somewhat equivalent. Yet, there may be some subtle difference in being formal. A topological space is a *pair* $(X,\tau)$ where $\tau$ is a topology on a *set* $X$, even though we often just write $X$ with $\tau$ omitted. You can say that a topological space is compact (since its topology is fixed), but you can't say that a set $X$ is compact since a set is not coming with a fixed topology. That's if you want to be formal, but in the daily math talks such subtleties may be redundant. What we often also say is that $A$ is a compact subset of $X$. To be formal, we have to say *the subset $A$ of the set $X$ is compact in the subspace topology induced by $(X,\tau)$* but I think one rarely does say/write such a long sentence.

Regarding your example, by a convergence subsequence one means that the limit belongs to the same space. The limit of $\{1/n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ is $0$ which does not belong to this set.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Heine-Borel itself does not require the completness of metric space. It states that the two statements above together with "finite intersection property" and "complete and totally bounded" all four are equivalent. However, "every sequence has a convergent subsequence" would imply completeness I believe.

Comment: @Xiao: indeed, in your case there is a different problem. You can't say that $\{1/n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ has a convergent subsequence as a space on its own, since its ``limit'' $0$ does not belong to it. Note that $0$ is the limit of this sequence in $[0,1]$, and when this sequence is considered on its own, you can't really talk about its limit.

Comment: Yes, I realized this as well, so I edited my post to add this remark. In the end, the two setting are actually the same. Thanks again for the reply!

Comment: @Xiao It's like you observe only this sequence, and there is nothing else around, and you feel this sequence shall converge (or formally, this feeling is called a Cauchy sequence), but there's nowhere to! And that's when you think of completing your space. When working with subspaces it is really important to understand that they are spaces/sets on their own, and hence all the limits etc. have to be inside them.